# Maya Python: window keeps closing itself

Tags: python, python-3.x, maya

I've run into a problem as I test adding arguments to my functions. Usually after def I put functionName(*args): and that works fine. The way my script works is simple, if "demoScriptWindow" already exists, then a new instance will override the previous window and close it. What I dont want is the window closing for whatever god forsaken reason when I hit the "Test Script" button. I just want the window to stay open when I press "Test Script" it seems simple but it's driving me insane.

To run the script it is simple, copy the long script below and save it to a .py file in d:\Users\user\Documents\maya\mayaVersion\scripts, to run the script copy the following line into a python tab, highlight, and numpad enter:

```
import demoScript
import imp
imp.reload (demoScript)
demoScript.gui()
```

here is the full script for anyone who wants to take a crack at it:

```
'''
import demoScript
import imp
imp.reload (demoScript)
demoScript.gui()
'''
import re
import maya.cmds as cmds
import maya.mel as mel
import maya.api.OpenMaya as om
import math

if cmds.window("demoScriptWindow", exists =True):
    cmds.deleteUI("demoScriptWindow", window = True)

myWindow = cmds.window("demoScriptWindow",t='DS Script Tester',rtf=1,w=100, h=100, toolbox=True)
column = cmds.columnLayout(adj=True)

def gui(*args):
    cmds.columnLayout(adjustableColumn=True)
    cmds.button(label= "Test Script",c=testScript)
    cmds.showWindow(myWindow)
    
def testScript(*args):
    import demoScript as ctrl
    import imp
    imp.reload(ctrl)
    ctrl.demoScript('lf1','arm','Ik')
    
    
def demoScript(side,limb,typ):
    ctrlN = "%s_%s%s_CTRL" % (side,limb,typ)
    print (ctrlN)
```

Comment: That's very confusing. The function testScript loads the demoScript (the script itself) and does a reload what automatically executes the cmd.deleteUI()? I heavily recommend not to execute UI scripts in the base level of a script and reload it at the same time. I suggest to use classes for UI's, they keep all data in one place.

Comment: Hey @haggikrey, thank you for the responce! I've tried playing with classess before: but they are still an area I vaguely understand. Do you have a good example or pointer explaining classes?

Comment: Not really, but there are a lot tutorials on youtube or other sources. You only need to understand the very basics, no need to dive deep into it to use it for UI. It's just important to know how to use __init__() and the class instance variables and method which are referenced by self.variablename and self.methodname().

Comment: Interesting: I'm going to look into that. I'll post the updated code here when I figure it out.

Comment: Is that "demoScript.py"? You probably want to do stuff behind a name main guard if you want to import it. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do

Answer (score 0):

all I had to do was cut out the all the reload and import options above "ctrl.demoScript('lf1','arm','Ik')"

```
'''
import demoScript
import imp
imp.reload (demoScript)
demoScript.gui()
'''
import re
import maya.cmds as cmds
import maya.mel as mel
import maya.api.OpenMaya as om
import math

if cmds.window("demoScriptWindow", exists =True):
    cmds.deleteUI("demoScriptWindow", window = True)

myWindow = cmds.window("demoScriptWindow",t='DS Script Tester',rtf=1,w=100, h=100, toolbox=True)
column = cmds.columnLayout(adj=True)

def gui(*args):
    cmds.columnLayout(adjustableColumn=True)
    cmds.button(label= "Test Script",c=testScript)
    cmds.showWindow(myWindow)
    
def testScript(*args):
    
    ctrl.demoScript('lf1','arm','Ik')
    
    
def demoScript(side,limb,typ):
    ctrlN = "%s_%s%s_CTRL" % (side,limb,typ)
    print (ctrlN)
```